# How do I execute some code in DAML N times?

Tags: daml

Say I have a choice that takes an integer that represents a count and I want to create a contract that number of times, i.e. execute some block of code that many times.

In Ruby for example this might look like this:

```
n.times do 
  #run some code here
end
```

How do I achieve this in DAML?

Answer (score 2):

#### TLDR

To apply a ledger operation `N` times the easiest way is to use the `replicateA` function from `DA.Action`.

#### Example

```
daml 1.2
module ReplicateDaml
where

import DA.Action

template Demo
  with
    sig: Party
    total: Int
  where
    signatory sig

testReplicate = scenario do
  p <- getParty "party"
  let
    total = 10

  p `submit` replicateA total $ create Demo with sig=p; total
```

#### Discussion

The type signature for `replicateA` is:

```
-- | `replicateA n act` performs the action n times, gathering the results.
replicateA : (Applicative m) => Int -> m a -> m [a]
```

You can read this as:

> This function supports any type `m` that has an instance (implementation) for the `Applicative` typeclass (api or interface).
>   Its first parameter is an `Int`
>   Its second is an 'effect' of the type `m` that provides a value of type `a`
>   It returns the result of repeating the effect N times, collecting the results in a list

The `create` you describe is of type: `Update (ContractId a)`; and as `Update` instantiates (has an implementation for) the `Applicative` typeclass you can use any function that works on `Applicative`'s on `Update`'s — which naturally includes `replicateA`.

When used this way, substitute `Update` for `m` and `(ContractId t)` for `a` in the type signature, so:

`replicateA : Int -> Update (ContractId t) -> Update [ContractId t]`